# Buttons not working on JS inserted HTML but work on pure HTML

Tags: javascript

Got this [ToDoList app](https://jsfiddle.net/r5h7fbw9/)

All good, but after I insert a new activity (a new table) the buttons are not responsive even though I give them the classes and trigger the `eventListener`s.

Atm, my DOM consts are at the top of the JS page, but even when I moved them after the insertion of a new table (activity) in the JS page, still doesn't work.

tldr:

- remove and check buttons work with html that is preset on the page;
- remove and check buttons don't work with html that is inserted with js

```
newDiv.innerHTML = `<table class="table table-dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Title</th>
      <th scope="col">Priority</th>
      <th scope="col">Description</th>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Tasks</th>
      <th scope="col">Completed</th>
      <th scope="col">Remove</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">${newActivity.title}</th>
      <td>${newActivity.priority}</td>
      <td>${newActivity.description}</td>
      <td>${newActivity.date}</td>
      <td><i class="fas fa-sitemap"></i></td>
      <td><span class ='check-button'>X</span></td>
      <td><i class="fas fa-archive remove-button"></i></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>`;
```

Comment: 1) `document.querySelector()` only returns the very first match 2) even if you used `document.querySelectorAll()` instead, you'd get a NodeList containing only elements existing at the time of the call

Comment: you need to change your back ticks to single quotes  '<th scope="col">Title</th>'+ '<th scope="col">Priority</th>'+ the problem is in back tiks `